# importing 50gb+ dmp using imdp

Tags: impdp, datapump

Attempting to import 50GB+ dumpfile using impdp. Hitting the 11GB datafile limit. Never used oracle before. I created bigfile tablespace with autoextend on. Perhaps I should use different approach?

Comment: Which Oracle database are you using? A bigfile tablespace with 8K blocks can contain a 32 terabyte datafile.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle XE has an 11GB data limit. You need to upgrade to Standard Edition.